# Basic text similarity through WorldNet synsets for taxonomy mapping/merging

Tags: nltk, taxonomy, wordnet, drupal-taxonomy, sentence-similarity

I would like to implement a basic text similarity routine with semantic distance using WordNet and NLTK in Python. This is the idea: extend two concepts/prases/categories A and B with synsets, hyponyms, hypernyms, meronyms, metonyms and compute distance between two formed vectors, a and b. I am sot sure how I will compute these, maybe as a cosine distance.

My input data for most cases are not made of phrases but rather proper nouns or nouns (product names with brand or product categories). 
For example, I would like to determine that "resort" is a "luxury hotel" or "black caviar" is "gourmet", A - "black caviar", B - "gourmet".

To which extent this could works and how do I walk up and down WordNet to make it a bit more sophisticated then one level up and down with hypo/hyper-nyms.

I am looking for simple basic solution that works well enough, not using sophisticated things like Whoosh or something.

Should I use something better then WordNet?

---

UPDATE:

I am processing each noun phrase the following way (using NLTK & WordNet):
1. For each word in a phrase I collect a synset (nouns only), then I complement it with a synset of hypernyms and hyponyms for each element in the synset. For now, I grab all the synsets into the list ignoring the hierarchy.
2. I repeat the process for the keywords describing each of my categories category. 
3. Now I have a list of synsets for each category and for my target. Just compute a distance to each (cosine or Wu and Palmer's distance). I collect pairwise distances in my two vectors, summing them, normalizing by the number of keywords describing the category or a target. Then I pick a min distance.

Sounds like pretty basic and inefficient. What is the next step to make it better?

I am interested to do it from scratch, it's also the best exercise to understand how things work and how it needs to be done.

---

EXAMPLE:
word_list - target:
['school', 'kids', 'teacher']

categories:
[['business', 'organization', 'company'],['education', 'school', 'university']]

extended list for target concept 'education', 3 keywords:
[Synset('school.n.01'), Synset('school.n.02'), Synset('school.n.03'), Synset('school.n.04'), Synset('school.n.05'), Synset('school.n.06'), Synset('school.n.07'), Synset('child.n.01'), Synset('kid.n.02'), Synset('kyd.n.01'), Synset('child.n.02'), Synset('kid.n.05'), Synset('teacher.n.01'), Synset('teacher.n.02'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('building.n.01'), Synset('education.n.03'), Synset('body.n.02'), Synset('time_period.n.01'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('animal_group.n.01'), Synset('academy.n.03'), Synset('alma_mater.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.01'), Synset('correspondence_school.n.01'), Synset('crammer.n.03'), Synset('dance_school.n.01'), Synset('dancing_school.n.01'), Synset('day_school.n.02'), Synset('direct-grant_school.n.01'), Synset('driving_school.n.01'), Synset('finishing_school.n.01'), Synset('flying_school.n.01'), Synset('grade_school.n.01'), Synset('graduate_school.n.01'), Synset('language_school.n.01'), Synset('night_school.n.01'), Synset('nursing_school.n.01'), Synset('private_school.n.01'), Synset('public_school.n.01'), Synset('religious_school.n.01'), Synset('riding_school.n.01'), Synset('secondary_school.n.01'), Synset('secretarial_school.n.01'), Synset('sunday_school.n.01'), Synset('technical_school.n.01'), Synset('training_school.n.01'), Synset('veterinary_school.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.02'), Synset('day_school.n.03'), Synset('art_nouveau.n.01'), Synset('ashcan_school.n.01'), Synset('deconstructivism.n.01'), Synset('historical_school.n.01'), Synset('lake_poets.n.01'), Synset('pointillism.n.01'), Synset('secession.n.01')]

Extended list for category concept 'business', 3 keywords, 223 in extended list:
[Synset('business.n.01'), Synset('commercial_enterprise.n.02'), Synset('occupation.n.01'), Synset('business.n.04'), Synset('business.n.05'), Synset('business.n.06'), Synset('business.n.07'), Synset('clientele.n.01'), Synset('business.n.09'), Synset('organization.n.01'), Synset('arrangement.n.03'), Synset('administration.n.02'), Synset('organization.n.04'), Synset('organization.n.05'), Synset('organization.n.06'), Synset('constitution.n.02'), Synset('company.n.01'), Synset('company.n.02'), Synset('company.n.03'), Synset('company.n.04'), Synset('caller.n.01'), Synset('company.n.06'), Synset('party.n.03'), Synset('ship's_company.n.01'), Synset('company.n.09'), Synset('enterprise.n.02'), Synset('commerce.n.01'), Synset('activity.n.01'), Synset('concern.n.04'), Synset('aim.n.02'), Synset('business_activity.n.01'), Synset('sector.n.02'), Synset('people.n.01'), Synset('acting.n.01'), Synset('social_group.n.01'), Synset('structure.n.03'), Synset('body.n.02'), Synset('administration.n.01'), Synset('orderliness.n.01'), Synset('activity.n.01'), Synset('beginning.n.05'), Synset('institution.n.01'), Synset('army_unit.n.01'), Synset('friendship.n.01'), Synset('organization.n.01'), Synset('visitor.n.01'), Synset('social_gathering.n.01'), Synset('set.n.05'), Synset('complement.n.03'), Synset('unit.n.03'), Synset('agency.n.02'), Synset('brokerage.n.02'), Synset('carrier.n.05'), Synset('chain.n.04'), Synset('firm.n.01'), Synset('franchise.n.02'), Synset('manufacturer.n.01'), Synset('partnership.n.01'), Synset('processor.n.01'), Synset('shipbuilder.n.03'), Synset('underperformer.n.02'), Synset('advertising.n.02'), Synset('agribusiness.n.01'), Synset('butchery.n.02'), Synset('construction.n.07'), Synset('discount_business.n.01'), Synset('employee-owned_enterprise.n.01'), Synset('field.n.06'), Synset('finance.n.01'), Synset('fishing.n.02'), Synset('industry.n.02'), Synset('packaging.n.01'), Synset('printing.n.02'), Synset('publication.n.04'), Synset('real-estate_business.n.01'), Synset('storage.n.03'), Synset('tourism.n.01'), Synset('transportation.n.05'), Synset('venture.n.03'), Synset('accountancy.n.01'), Synset('appointment.n.05'), Synset('career.n.01'), Synset('catering.n.01'), Synset('confectionery.n.03'), Synset('employment.n.02'), Synset('farming.n.02'), Synset('game.n.10'), Synset('metier.n.02'), Synset('photography.n.03'), Synset('position.n.06'), Synset('profession.n.02'), Synset('sport.n.02'), Synset('trade.n.02'), Synset('treadmill.n.03'), Synset('occasions.n.01'), Synset('land-office_business.n.01'), Synset('trade.n.03'), Synset('big_business.n.01'), Synset('shtik.n.02'), Synset('adhocracy.n.01'), Synset('affiliate.n.02'), Synset('alliance.n.03'), Synset('association.n.01'), Synset('blue.n.03'), Synset('bureaucracy.n.03'), Synset('company.n.04'), Synset('defense.n.09'), Synset('deputation.n.01'), Synset('enterprise.n.02'), Synset('establishment.n.05'), Synset('federation.n.01'), Synset('fiefdom.n.02'), Synset('fire_brigade.n.01'), Synset('force.n.04'), Synset('girl_scouts.n.01'), Synset('grey.n.04'), Synset('hierarchy.n.02'), Synset('host.n.06'), Synset('institution.n.01'), Synset('line_of_defense.n.01'), Synset('line_organization.n.01'), Synset('machine.n.03'), Synset('machine.n.05'), Synset('musical_organization.n.01'), Synset('nongovernmental_organization.n.01'), Synset('party.n.01'), Synset('peace_corps.n.01'), Synset('polity.n.02'), Synset('pool.n.03'), Synset('professional_organization.n.01'), Synset('quango.n.01'), Synset('tammany_hall.n.01'), Synset('union.n.01'), Synset('unit.n.03'), Synset('calendar.n.01'), Synset('classification_system.n.01'), Synset('contrivance.n.04'), Synset('coordinate_system.n.01'), Synset('data_structure.n.01'), Synset('design.n.02'), Synset('distribution.n.01'), Synset('genetic_map.n.01'), Synset('kinship_system.n.01'), Synset('lattice.n.01'), Synset('living_arrangement.n.01'), Synset('ontology.n.01'), Synset('county_council.n.01'), Synset('curia.n.01'), Synset('executive.n.02'), Synset('government_officials.n.01'), Synset('judiciary.n.01'), Synset('management.n.02'), Synset('top_brass.n.01'), Synset('nonprofit_organization.n.01'), Synset('rationalization.n.04'), Synset('reorganization.n.01'), Synset('self-organization.n.01'), Synset('syndication.n.01'), Synset('listing.n.02'), Synset('order.n.15'), Synset('randomization.n.01'), Synset('systematization.n.01'), Synset('territorialization.n.01'), Synset('collectivization.n.01'), Synset('colonization.n.01'), Synset('communization.n.02'), Synset('federation.n.03'), Synset('unionization.n.01'), Synset('broadcasting_company.n.01'), Synset('bureau_de_change.n.01'), Synset('car_company.n.01'), Synset('closed_shop.n.01'), Synset('corporate_investor.n.01'), Synset('distributor.n.03'), Synset('dot-com.n.01'), Synset('drug_company.n.01'), Synset('east_india_company.n.01'), Synset('electronics_company.n.01'), Synset('film_company.n.01'), Synset('food_company.n.01'), Synset('furniture_company.n.01'), Synset('holding_company.n.01'), Synset('joint-stock_company.n.01'), Synset('limited_company.n.01'), Synset('livery_company.n.01'), Synset('mining_company.n.01'), Synset('mover.n.04'), Synset('oil_company.n.01'), Synset('open_shop.n.01'), Synset('packaging_company.n.01'), Synset('pipeline_company.n.01'), Synset('printing_concern.n.01'), Synset('record_company.n.01'), Synset('service.n.04'), Synset('shipper.n.02'), Synset('shipping_company.n.01'), Synset('steel_company.n.01'), Synset('stock_company.n.01'), Synset('subsidiary_company.n.01'), Synset('target_company.n.01'), Synset('think_tank.n.01'), Synset('transportation_company.n.01'), Synset('union_shop.n.01'), Synset('white_knight.n.01'), Synset('trainband.n.01'), Synset('freemasonry.n.01'), Synset('ballet_company.n.01'), Synset('chorus.n.05'), Synset('circus.n.01'), Synset('minstrel_show.n.01'), Synset('minstrelsy.n.01'), Synset('opera_company.n.01'), Synset('theater_company.n.01'), Synset('attendance.n.03'), Synset('cohort.n.01'), Synset('number.n.07'), Synset('fatigue_party.n.01'), Synset('landing_party.n.01'), Synset('party_to_the_action.n.01'), Synset('rescue_party.n.01'), Synset('search_party.n.01'), Synset('stretcher_party.n.01'), Synset('war_party.n.01')]

Extended list for category concept 'education' - 97 synsets:
[Synset('education.n.01'), Synset('education.n.02'), Synset('education.n.03'), Synset('education.n.04'), Synset('education.n.05'), Synset('department_of_education.n.01'), Synset('school.n.01'), Synset('school.n.02'), Synset('school.n.03'), Synset('school.n.04'), Synset('school.n.05'), Synset('school.n.06'), Synset('school.n.07'), Synset('university.n.01'), Synset('university.n.02'), Synset('university.n.03'), Synset('activity.n.01'), Synset('content.n.05'), Synset('learning.n.01'), Synset('profession.n.02'), Synset('upbringing.n.01'), Synset('executive_department.n.01'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('building.n.01'), Synset('education.n.03'), Synset('body.n.02'), Synset('time_period.n.01'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('animal_group.n.01'), Synset('body.n.02'), Synset('establishment.n.04'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('coeducation.n.01'), Synset('continuing_education.n.01'), Synset('course.n.01'), Synset('elementary_education.n.01'), Synset('extension.n.04'), Synset('extracurricular_activity.n.01'), Synset('higher_education.n.01'), Synset('secondary_education.n.01'), Synset('team_teaching.n.01'), Synset('work-study_program.n.01'), Synset('enlightenment.n.01'), Synset('eruditeness.n.01'), Synset('experience.n.01'), Synset('foundation.n.04'), Synset('physical_education.n.01'), Synset('acculturation.n.03'), Synset('mastering.n.01'), Synset('school.n.03'), Synset('self-education.n.01'), Synset('special_education.n.01'), Synset('vocational_training.n.01'), Synset('teaching.n.01'), Synset('academy.n.03'), Synset('alma_mater.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.01'), Synset('correspondence_school.n.01'), Synset('crammer.n.03'), Synset('dance_school.n.01'), Synset('dancing_school.n.01'), Synset('day_school.n.02'), Synset('direct-grant_school.n.01'), Synset('driving_school.n.01'), Synset('finishing_school.n.01'), Synset('flying_school.n.01'), Synset('grade_school.n.01'), Synset('graduate_school.n.01'), Synset('language_school.n.01'), Synset('night_school.n.01'), Synset('nursing_school.n.01'), Synset('private_school.n.01'), Synset('public_school.n.01'), Synset('religious_school.n.01'), Synset('riding_school.n.01'), Synset('secondary_school.n.01'), Synset('secretarial_school.n.01'), Synset('sunday_school.n.01'), Synset('technical_school.n.01'), Synset('training_school.n.01'), Synset('veterinary_school.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.02'), Synset('day_school.n.03'), Synset('art_nouveau.n.01'), Synset('ashcan_school.n.01'), Synset('deconstructivism.n.01'), Synset('historical_school.n.01'), Synset('lake_poets.n.01'), Synset('pointillism.n.01'), Synset('secession.n.01'), Synset('gown.n.02'), Synset('varsity.n.01'), Synset('city_university.n.01'), Synset('oxbridge.n.01'), Synset('redbrick_university.n.01'), Synset('multiversity.n.01'), Synset('open_university.n.01')]

Extended list for my target, 57 synsets: 
[Synset('school.n.01'), Synset('school.n.02'), Synset('school.n.03'), Synset('school.n.04'), Synset('school.n.05'), Synset('school.n.06'), Synset('school.n.07'), Synset('child.n.01'), Synset('kid.n.02'), Synset('kyd.n.01'), Synset('child.n.02'), Synset('kid.n.05'), Synset('teacher.n.01'), Synset('teacher.n.02'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('building.n.01'), Synset('education.n.03'), Synset('body.n.02'), Synset('time_period.n.01'), Synset('educational_institution.n.01'), Synset('animal_group.n.01'), Synset('academy.n.03'), Synset('alma_mater.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.01'), Synset('correspondence_school.n.01'), Synset('crammer.n.03'), Synset('dance_school.n.01'), Synset('dancing_school.n.01'), Synset('day_school.n.02'), Synset('direct-grant_school.n.01'), Synset('driving_school.n.01'), Synset('finishing_school.n.01'), Synset('flying_school.n.01'), Synset('grade_school.n.01'), Synset('graduate_school.n.01'), Synset('language_school.n.01'), Synset('night_school.n.01'), Synset('nursing_school.n.01'), Synset('private_school.n.01'), Synset('public_school.n.01'), Synset('religious_school.n.01'), Synset('riding_school.n.01'), Synset('secondary_school.n.01'), Synset('secretarial_school.n.01'), Synset('sunday_school.n.01'), Synset('technical_school.n.01'), Synset('training_school.n.01'), Synset('veterinary_school.n.01'), Synset('conservatory.n.02'), Synset('day_school.n.03'), Synset('art_nouveau.n.01'), Synset('ashcan_school.n.01'), Synset('deconstructivism.n.01'), Synset('historical_school.n.01'), Synset('lake_poets.n.01'), Synset('pointillism.n.01'), Synset('secession.n.01')]

---

I have 3 vectors, target - 57, business - 223, and education - 97.

Now compute pairwise Wu and Palmer's distances between target and business, divide by 57x223=12711; between target and education, divide by 57x97=5529.

target to business distance: 2305.709117171037 / 5529 = 0.9125370052417936
target to education distance: 5045.417101981877 / 12711 = 0.39693313680921066

Min distance is to education. That's a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

WordNet + some similarity can be of a solution.
You can also use Word2Vec to determine semantic distance of words that you get from WordNet synset/*nyms search.

Maybe someone could help with a particular library (nothing pops in my mind at the moment that you could use directly).

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec for semantic representation + a maximum likelihood method as described in the paper below would be a good approach to merge two taxonomies: http://www.ideal.ece.utexas.edu/papers/rajan05aaai.pdf